# Program stays in background after reading from pipe

Tags: c, process, io, pipe

I am doing an exercise with pipes, basically i have to write a program that receives a string and it converts it to an int (i am not allowed to edit the execise code) and i don't understand why the process generated from my program doesn't stop.

This is the exercise:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PIPEOUT "/tmp/pipeOut"
#define MAXNUM 1024
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define CHALLENGES 3

int main() {
    int fd_in, fd_out, i;
    int challenge;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];

    unlink(PIPEOUT);

    if (mkfifo(PIPEOUT,0666)<0) {
        perror("Error while creating pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fd_out = open(PIPEOUT, O_WRONLY);

    if (fd_out<0) {
        perror("Error while opening pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    srandom(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<CHALLENGES;i++) {
        challenge = random()%MAXNUM;
        if (snprintf(buffer,MAXBUF,"%d\n",challenge)>=MAXBUF) {
            printf("Buffer error!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Invio %s",buffer);
        if(write(fd_out,buffer,strlen(buffer))<0) {
            perror("error during write");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code that has to work with the exercise:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PIPEOUT "/tmp/pipeOut"
#define MAXNUM 1024
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define CHALLENGES 3

void main(){
    int fd0,fd1;    // pipe descriptors
    char c;         // read char
    char str[1024]; // buffer
    int index = 0;  // index of buffer
    int num = 0;
    memset(str,'\0',1024); // init string

    fd0 = open(PIPEOUT,O_RDONLY);

    if (fd0<0) {
        perror("Error with pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(read(fd0,&c,1)) {
        if(c != '\n') {
            printf("received: %c\n", c);
            str[index++] = c;
        } else {
            num = atoi(str);
            printf("print number: %d\n", num);
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    close(fd0);
}
```

To execute the exercise i use the following command:

```
(sleep 1; ./solution) & ./exercise
```

If i do:

```
ps
```

it shows that the program is still running but doing nothing (this should be called "zombie process" if i am not wrong cause it never gets terminated), the problem is that the strings sent by the exercise don't end with '\0' and we have to figure out a way to make the process end, so it's almost certainly the while condition that is keeping the process running and the problem is that i don't really know how to stop it.

Comment: Aside: The return type of `main` should be `int`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is most surely not that one i think.

Comment: Which program are you running first? If the exercise starts second, I think the `unlink(PIPEOUT);` line will break the pipe your program has created. Does this work if the exercise is started first, then your program is run?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't stop"?  Is it blocked on `open`?  Show how you are executing the programs.

Comment: The exerciser program definitely needs to run first, otherwise it will be writing to a different pipe than the one that the client is reading (if a leftover pipe exists from an earlier run). Actually, both the exerciser and the client would be blocked on `open` in that case.

Comment: i use this command to start the program: ```(sleep 1; ./solution) & ./exercise```

Comment: If you run it that way, almost certainly the `exercise` is running first. `solution` then unlinks the fifo and creates a new one, then blocks trying to open it.

Comment: No, not really, the code gets executed properly, the problem is that at the end it becomes a zombie process (certainly because of the while condition), i don't know how to make it stop and i can't obviously kill it, it has to be a normal process end, i should also add that the strings sent by the exercise don't end with '\0'.

Comment: All processes become zombies after they terminate.  (Most get out of the zombie state very quickly.) If the process is stuck in the loop, it is still running, and not a zombie.

Comment: Yes i am sorry, i found out later that it is supposedly stuck in the loop.